# Mongoose.connect() doesn't respond

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm learning how to use Mongodb with Mongoose in Nodejs. The course I'm following uses version 5.0.1 so I was using it at first. I created a local database with Mongodb compass and connected it. My system is Win10.
VS code 1.74.2.
Node 18.12.1.
Mongodb 4.13
Mongoose 5.0.1 then upgraded to 5.13.15.
I can connect the database with older version of Mongoose but can not save any data, and upgrade newer version just timeout when connecting.

I got the "Connected" message using this code with mongoose v5.0.1.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/playground')
    .then(() => console.log('Connected...'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Cound not connect...', err))
```

However, when I try to save a json object into the database using .save() function, it gave me error

```
errmsg: 'Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal',
  code: 352,
  codeName: 'UnsupportedOpQueryCommand'
```

Then I upgraded my mongoose and mongodb to the newest version, the same code gave me this warning

```
(node:10772) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10772) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
```

and gave me error

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
```

So I added the required option to the code

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/playground', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected...'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Cound not connect...', err))
```

it just times out without any output.

I can't find an answer anywhere. Any help is greatly appreciated!

SOLVED: change the url to 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/playground' solved the problem.

Comment: try changing `mongodb://localhost/playground` to `mongodb://localhost:27017/playground` and no need to pass extra options, those options warnings are deprecated in mongoose@6, more: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options

Comment: That still doesn't work. I changed it to 'mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/playground')' and added mongoose.set('strictQuery', false), now it works.

Answer (score 0):

you should give port to your Mongo like this:

```
mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test")
    .then(() => console.log(`\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m`, "**** MONGO CONNECT 
     ****"))
    .catch(() => console.log("eerro"))
```